# how to load user control from assemble DLL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

i want load my user control from my ".DLL" file. this is my code.
my user control work fine with register tag design time but in run time i see error.

```
        // load the assembly
        System.Reflection.Assembly assembly =
        Assembly.LoadFrom( Server.MapPath("~/bin/ActivePage.Coms.DLL"));

        // get the type
        Type t = assembly.GetType(name);

        // create an instance and add it.
        //
        Control c = (Control)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
        if (c != null)
        {
            Response.Write(c.ClientID);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(c);
        }
```

but is see this is error

:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
```

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

Comment: Give us a stack trace and a line number of ine where the exception happens

Answer (score 0):

when you pass user control name to assemble this line ;

```
Type t = assembly.GetType(name);
```

you must write full name with namespace example in my code is :

```
Type t = assembly.GetType("ASP.uc_contactform_ascx");
```

i pass name from route data with this line :

```
    string name = Page.RouteData.Values["name"].ToString();
```

after change url usercontrol name to full ("ASP.uc_contactform_ascx") my page work fine and load runtime user control from dll assemple solved.

contact me in asp.net development. tehhitech [at] live .com , skype = tarraharshad